# Viralheat API through R

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, geturl

I am trying to use the Viral Heat API in R for sentiment analysis. 
Directly hitting the browser with URL is returning proper results. 
http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json?text=i am happy&api_key=

Result:
{"prob":0.6652067715019936,"mood":"positive","text":"i am happy"}

But when running from R, it is returning NULL

R code:

```
vh_answer = getURL("http://www.viralheat.com/api/sentiment/review.json?text=i%20am%20happy&api_key=<my key>")
```

What is the reason? Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `followlocation = TRUE` in your `getURL` call.

I suspect you may also need to use `cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"))`, as well.

Comment: We use HTTPS for all our calls Raj
Viralheat Inc.